# Can someone suggest the command line script to get my Ubuntu 20.04 back to a normal boot after an update went bad?

Tags: boot

This happened about a month ago after a Ubuntu component update. Suddenly the boot gets error messages and my sd card slot won't work and my VMWare won't open anymore. My workaround was to boot to the Grub menu and select one of the boot options. This is too cumbersome to do every boot, so I just sleep the machine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtnKu.jpg)
The error message that show at the boot is attached as a photo. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated....would love to get back to a clean running 20.04.

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: This question is unlikely to be answered as asked. First, the question lacks sufficient details. You should provide a clear description of the problem and include details about what you've already done. You reference a temporary solution, but don't actually tell us about that solution. Secondly, instead of asking about your problem, you're asking how to apply a solution you think will work: a *bash script*. What you're asking is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  I suggest that you edit your question. Include details and make sure your question isn't an XY problem.

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/456947/error-32-while-establishing-usb-connection. Error -32 means a USB-related hardware fault, which might be simply a symptom of a dying power supply, or a miswired internal component...or might be something much more expensive. Not caused by Ubuntu. Any relation to a "Ubuntu component update" was coincidental, not causal. You have a hardware fault.

Comment: Thanks user535733. It is an older Toshiba laptop machine. I thought I could squeeze more time out of it, but I guess not.